# Azure Devops RestAPI returns max 2 levels of queryfolders

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to be able to make a table regarding queries with 'name','id','url' properties in an Azure Devops Project. These queries are sometimes located in a folderstructure more than 3 levels deep. Rest-api (using Powewrshell) doesn't let me go that deep. Is there an alternative?
Structure of folders is:

[image]

I tried the Azure Devops Restservices manually, using a browser and using a Powershell script. But it only shows "My Queries"and "Shared Queries" and one level below those.
The output of:
[https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/{Project}/_apis/wit/queries?&$depth=2&api-version=7.1-preview.2](https://dev.azure.com/%7BOrganization%7D/%7BProject%7D/_apis/wit/queries?&$depth=2&api-version=7.1-preview.2)
Result: it Only goes to level 2 (2nd Level Folder is shown, not deeper than that).

I hope there is an alternative, or else restructure the folder hierarchy....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because other folders in the `children` section:

[image]

To get the next level, you may add the needed path to URL:
`https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/wit/queries/Shared Queries/Current Iteration?&$depth=2&api-version=7.1-preview.2`

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is spot on, and often afterwards one embarrassedly thinks: Why couldn't I think of that . Thank you very much!